# Black screen with blinking cursor when restart [18.04]

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

This is my first time trying out ubuntu and so far the only issue I've got is that whenever I restart it ends up in a black screen with a blinking cursor and I need to hard shut down.

I'm using:
 - Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro.
 - Core i5 8250U
 - Nvidia mx150
 - Samsung pm961 ssd
 - 8GB RAM.

Also I'm using Nvidia proprietary drivers (Nvidia 390)

I would be very thankful if you can help me with this !!!